# UIMenuController inside UIWebView issue with targetrect and Direction only in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7

Strange Behaviour in iOS7.when i tried to print the value of frame is not changing but UIMenuController is going somewhere in the UIWebView.This is only happening in iOS7.Its working properly in iOS6 versions.

is there any relation b/w setTargetRect and menuFrame for UIMenuController...As i m changing rect by using setTargetRect method but unfortunately menuFrame is not appropriately changing and it's going to somewhere in UIWebView in iOS7..

Here is the piece of code....

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showMenuController:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];

}

-(void)showMenuController:(id)notif
{
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = self.menuControlArray;
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setTargetRect:[self cursorRect] inView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect([self cursorRect]));
}

- (void)formatFont:(id)send {
    _fontEditing = YES;
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = YES;
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];
}
```

Comment: I found one thing...is there any relation b/w setTargetRect and menuFrame for UIMenuController...As i m changing rect by using setTargetRect method but unfortunately menuFrame is changing to some other rect and it's going to somewhere in UIWebView..Any idea why its so??

Comment: But the problem is only with the UINavigationController..If the UIWebView or UITextView is in UIViewController it's working fine